# How to run a particular stage in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How to run a particular stage in the `Jenkins declarative pipeline`?

**Example:**

- Stage 1 --> Gitlab code Checkout
- Stage 2 --> Sonarqube scan
- Stage 3  --> Deploy Nexus artifact
- Stage 4 --> Fortify check

If I wanted to `run only the stage 3(Deploy Nexus artifact) without running the stage 1, 2 and 4.` How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [when](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) expression with every stage that you want to skip. The variables `checkoutCode`, `runSonarScan`, `deployNexusArtifact` can be set as environment variables statically or dynamically.

```
environment {
   checkoutCode = true
   runSonarScan = true
   deployNexusArtifact = true
}

stage('Gitlab code Checkout') {
    when { expression { "${checkoutCode}" == 'true' } }
    ...
}

stage('Sonarqube scan') {
    when { expression { "${runSonarScan}" == 'true' } }
    ...
}

stage('Deploy Nexus artifact') {
    when { expression { "${deployNexusArtifact}" == 'true' } }
    ...
}
```